# Opening and editing MS word file in visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, oledb, ole

I'm creating a program for my school project that will allow me to open a MS Word document and read it as a string. Perform a few modifications on the string and then save the new string as a MS Word file again. 
Now I know this can be done by OLE automation but being pretty new to programming I don't understand how to do that. 
Can someone post a code snippet telling me how to do this ? Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might look at autohotkey as a really round-about way of doing this.  AutoHotKey is a program that lets you automate keyboard presses.  You could automate opening and closing word easily. http://ahkscript.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think MS Word stores its files as a compressed xml markup file. First of all look for how to decompress/decrypt it into proper xml, then find all the string tags and write them out. Also, you can deduce the markup of an empty simple Word file, and add the xml tags to it to create your own MS document.